# Toggle button loading state Error: Too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a 'loading' class to my button as soon as the user clicks on it. I'm very new to React and I remember seeing something like this before about doing this inside a function (which I thought I did) but I get the `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` error in my browser.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchButton () {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <button className={loading ? 'loading ui purple button' : 'ui purple button'} onClick={() => setLoading(!loading) }>
      <i className="icon search"></i>
      Search
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Do you have codesandbox, jsfiddle or anything that will help in reproducing?

Comment: @PramodMali Thanks for your reply. This error went away after I killed the server.

Comment: This component is not having issue, i think the issue exists in the parent component, where you are importing this component